# Switching from a SpriteKit scene to an UIView in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm developing a Swift SpriteKit game and I need a little help. I have my game scene where the game runs and when the player dies I want to load another scene with buttons and labels for score, but I want this scene to be an UIView instead of a SpriteKit scene. How can I load the UIView from the SpriteKit scene? Works with present scene? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to show a popup-menu, you can access the view of your SKScene and add your `UIView` as subview:

```
self.view?.addSubview(yourView)
```

Or if you want to move to another `UIViewcontroller`, you can access the `rootViewController` of your view and present your viewcontroller from there:

```
self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent: YourViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: It works but I get an issue that says Unsupported Configuration that says the scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points. I don't have entry points because the only way to enter is by code, when you lose (without buttons).